# How do I edit attritubes of HTML tags using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML tag like the following:

```
print(tag)

<td style="background-color: #e5e5e5;">
  <p style="
     margin: 0; 
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 16px;
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     ">10</p>
</td>
```

I can update the value from 10 to 15 in the tag with BeautifulSoup:

```
tag.p.contents[0].replaceWith(str(15))
```

However, I haven't figured out a way to update the values in the style tags; because they seem to be a part of their parent, or 'base' tags.

For example, how would I update the tag to the following?

```
print(tag) --> 
<td style="background-color: #762157;">
   <p style="
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 17px;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      ">10</p>
</td>
```

I change the `background-color` to `#762157` and `line-height` to `17px;`

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the html you posted, `style` is not a tag, but an attribute of the `p` tag. Here is one way to modify that `p` attribute (and you can apply the same for `td` style attribute):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<td style="background-color: #e5e5e5;">
  <p style="
     margin: 0; 
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 16px;
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     ">10</p>
</td>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
print('OLD SOUP')
print(soup.prettify())
print('______________')
p_style_attribute = soup.select_one('p').get('style')
new_p_style_attr = '''
margin: 3; 
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;

'''
soup.select_one('p')['style'] = new_p_style_attr
print('NEW SOUP')
print(soup.prettify())
```

This will print out in terminal:

```
OLD SOUP
<td style="background-color: #e5e5e5;">
 <p style="
     margin: 0; 
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 16px;
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     ">
  10
 </p>
</td>

______________
NEW SOUP
<td style="background-color: #e5e5e5;">
 <p style="
margin: 3; 
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;

">
  10
 </p>
</td>
```

Here is the documentation for BeautifulSoup:

https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A `regex` approach. Collect the new information about the style into a dictionary, `(tag_name, attr_value)`-pairs and pass it to `update_style` function for an in-place modification of the `soup`.

The substitution is invariant wrt white spaces and `;`. A `**subs` could also be possible.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re


def update_style(soup, subs):
    for tag_name, attr in subs.items():
        tag = soup.find(tag_name)
        k, v = attr.split(':')
        tag['style'] = re.sub(rf'{k}:(.+);', f'{k}: {v.strip(" ;")};', tag['style'])


html = '''
<td style="background-color: #e5e5e5;">
  <p style="
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 16px;
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     ">10</p>
</td>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

subs = {'td': 'background-color: #762157;', 'p': 'line-height: 17px;'}
update_style(soup, subs)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: One shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. because HTML isn't parseable with regex. Regex isn't equipped to parse HTML.. and for a thorough explanation as of why your answer will probably bring Apocalypse upon us all, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags At this point, I am afraid to even touch your post with a downvote.

Comment: I am aware of it. I am parsing string with tag's attributes not the html itself... that's why I used `bs4` to move along the tree